# React-Native: ScrollView, refs, and custom components

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to understand how to do 2 things in React-Native.

Question 1: I have a component and another custom component that I need to scroll inside of a ScrollView.

The problem is that I'm too new to react-native to understand how from my 'child' component I can get access to the scrollview. Note: if I don't use the custom component and put everything into the MainView component, the code works fine.

Here's the basics of the code:

```
class MainView extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
    <ScrollView ref='scrollView'>
      <MyCustomComponent />
    </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}


class MyCustomComponent extends React.Component{

  inputFocused(refName) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let scrollResponder = this.refs.scrollView.getScrollResponder();
      scrollResponder.scrollResponderScrollNativeHandleToKeyboard(
        React.findNodeHandle(this.refs[refName]),
        110, //additionalOffset
        true
      );
    }, 50);
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <TextInput ref='fieldtitle'
      onFocus={this.inputFocused.bind(this, 'fieldtitle')}
      />

    )
  }

}
```

Question 2: how can I have my 'child' (MyCustomComponent) component call a method that is implemented on the parent component (MainView). The reason for this is that I have a bunch of slightly different 'MyCustomComponents' and I don't want to implement the same boilerplate code to scroll in all of them.

Answer (score 0):

For question 2: 
The approach I am using is to pass the method into props of your child component and call it when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @yang-lei for pointing me in one direction. Here's what I ended up doing:

For 'child' component in the 'parent' component, passed in a function:

```
<MyCustomComponent onFocusFunction={this.gainFocus.bind(this)} onDismissFunction={this.dismissFocus.bind(this)} />
```

In MyCustomComponent:

```
inputFocused(refName) {
  this.props.onFocusFunction(this, refName)
}

dismissFocus(refName) {
  this.props.onDismissFunction(this, refName)
}

render() {

  var field = this.props.fieldInfo;
  placeholder = field.placeholder ? field.placeholder : ""

  return (
    <View style={styles.inputRow}>
    <Text style={styles.textField}>{this.props.fieldInfo.title}</Text>
    <TextInput ref={field.title}
      style={styles.textInput}
      onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
      keyboardType='email-address'
      placeholder={placeholder}
      onFocus={this.inputFocused.bind(this, field.title)}
      onBlur={this.dismissFocus.bind(this, field.title)}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

In 'parent' component:

```
gainFocus(view, refName) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let scrollResponder = this.refs.scrollView.getScrollResponder();
    scrollResponder.scrollResponderScrollNativeHandleToKeyboard(
      React.findNodeHandle(view.refs[refName]),
      110, //additionalOffset
      true
    );
  }, 0);
}

dismissFocus(view, refName) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let scrollResponder = this.refs.scrollView.getScrollResponder();
    scrollResponder.scrollResponderScrollTo(
    )
  }, 0);
}
```